# How to show that there's exactly one element in multiple member collections that meets given criteria in UML?

Tags: uml, member, class-diagram

I have a UML diagram where a football team consists of field players (10 or more) and goalkeepers(1, 2, or 3). How can I show using UML that in a team one of the players is the skipper?

[image]

Comment: That would be by adding an attribute with a constraint. OCL would be perfect but a plain text `{ one of ... }`  will do as well. You could also use an association towards `FootballPlayer` with the `subsets` constraint.

Comment: Do you see the skipper as a distinct class (somewhat like Goalkeeper) or do you see it as a role/additional information of a field player that doesn’t change its behavior (I mean of the objects in your system, not irl)?

Comment: @Christophe
I see it as additional information. The skipper has to be a goalkeeper or a field player, so it could be added as a isSkipper boolean inside the FootballPlayer class but I'm not sure how to express this constraint of having exactly one skipper in a team within the FootballTeam class.

Comment: @FriedrichNietzsche interesting, because your model doesn’t associate  player with the team directly, yet the constraint on skipper is globally for a team, goalkeeper and fieldplayer confused.  This is important information: could you edit your question to make it clear for rverbody? (not everybody goes through all the comments)

Comment: An additional remark is that isSkipper is something that would describe the role of player in a team, whereas placing it as property of the player would make this property independent of the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With your current model

With your given classes and associations, you would express this as a constraint:

> A Constraint is an assertion that indicates a restriction that must be satisfied by any valid realization of the model containing the Constraint.

A constraint is indicated as an expression between curly braces `{ ... }` that corresponds to a boolean expression expected to be true. It can be:

- plain text understandable by everybody  e.g. `{ only one player in a team have isSkipper true }`;
- or more formally, typically in OCL, such as  `{ self.fieldPlayers->select(isSkipper)->size() + self.goalKeepers->select(isSkipper)->size() = 1 }`.  As many people, I'm not OCL fluent, this is why I recommend plaintext, since the idea of a model is to communicate a design **more easily** to its readers.

I expressed these constraints with the `FootballTeam` context (i.e. constraint attached to that class), as it is a constraint fo the whole team.

### But...

The idea of having `isSkipper` as an attribute of a player does not seem the best idea in view of separation of concerns:  the skipper role is dependent on the team,  so it would be better shown in an association class.

Moreover, it is troublesome to have roles such as goal keeper and field player as a specialization, but have the skipper -- yet another role -- as a boolean field might be cumbersome to implement any sound OOP polymorphic design.

Last but not least, keep in mind that a football team may evolve and that all conditions such as multiplicities might only be fulfilled when thee am is completed, thus creating some disconnection between the model and the reality of your code.

I therefore would strongly suggest a design like:

```
+----------------+ *                    1 +--------------+
| FootballPlayer |------------------------| FootballTeam |
+----------------+           :            +--------------+
                             :
                      +------------+           
                      | TeamPlayer |
                      +------------+
```

The `TeamPlayer` class is about everything that is dependent on the player AND the team.

Then I'd suggest to design a `Role` class associated with `TeamPlayer`.  You'd typically have 1 role for a player.  The role would be specialized into `GoalKeeper` vs. `FieldPlayer`,  and you could make `Skipper` a [decorator](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) that can superpose to one of the two other.

This does not remove the need to express your constraint, but the model would be more powerful.  Last but not least,  I'd see a `/isTeamValid` derived attribute that would be true if all your current constraints are fulfilled (including the counts of the player with goal keeper and field player and skipper roles). The advantage is that it lets you to build a team and evolve the composition of a team and roles (